# how to left Join tables and keep the order?

Tags: sql

i tried to join those two tables like this:

```
select 
    T2.* 
from 
    (SELECT DISTINCT DésignationBDC2 FROM pdc2 where BDC3 like '%01|06|02%') AS T1
    LEFT JOIN (select DésignationBDC2, COULEUR from pdc2 where Id=60) AS T2 ON T1.DésignationBDC2 = T2.DésignationBDC2
```

these tables are :

[image]

[image]

however, i get this :

[image]

and as you can see, the order of "DésignationBDC2" is lost from the first table.
How can i avoid this ?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images or links to images.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. BTW, you use a column `Id`  which doesn't exist in your sample data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use sub-query you can do `left join` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT C2.DésignationBDC2, C22.COULEUR  
FROM pdc2 AS C2 LEFT JOIN
     pdc2 AS C22
     ON C22.DésignationBDC2  = C2.DésignationBDC2 AND C22.ID = 60
WHERE P2.BDC3 like '%01|06|02%'
ORDER BY C2.DésignationBDC2;
```